# Including a library from a github branch in react-native

Tags: javascript, ios, git, react-native, lightbox

I'm trying to include a react-native package from a branch that includes a feature I'd like to use. Read the documentation and it seems like I can basically include it like this: `"react-native-lightbox":"git://github.com/oblador/react-native-lightbox.git#navigator-refactor"` which seems to have worked.

Then, in my component where I'd like to use it, I have:

`import Lightbox from 'react-native-lightbox';`

However, when `<Lightbox>` gets rendered like this:

```
 <Lightbox activeProps={{width: 200, height: 200, alignSelf: 'center'}} >
   <Image
     style={[currentUser ? styles.currentUserChatImage : styles.chatImage]}
     source={{uri: item['url']}}
     resizeMode="cover"
     />
 </Lightbox>
```

I get this error:

[image: Element type is invalid]

I'm confident I'm doing something wrong but I'm stuck on what that is. I was hoping someone could offer suggestions / help. Ty.

Comment: I'm guessing you actually did `<Lightbox />` vs `<Lightbox>` ? Also did you restart your packager?

Comment: hi nader...yes to restart. Actually `<Lightbox>` then `<Image />` (with some props) then `</Lightbox>`...updated.

Comment: I also tried the same and go error. according to me navigator branch is not stable. so use react-native-image-zoom instead or photoView https://github.com/alwx/react-native-photo-view